# PartnerCenter Graph API equivalent for the commands "Get-PartnerAzureBillingAccount" and "Set-PartnerAzureBillingPolicy"

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

As Microsoft forces migration away from DAP to GDAP, we are moving away from the PartnerCenter module. We need to replace the commands Get-PartnerAzureBillingAccount

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/partnercenter/get-partnerazurebillingaccount?view=partnercenterps-3.0

and Set-PartnerAzureBillingPolicy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/partnercenter/set-partnerazurebillingpolicy?view=partnercenterps-3.0

with direct Graph API calls. From reading through all the API documentation, it seems as though there is no way to do this. Does anyone know of endpoints that fulfill this need?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API doesn't have any endpoints related to Partner Center.

There is standalone [Partner Center REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/partner-center-rest/) but I'm not familiar with this API, so you need to go through the API by yourself.

[Get billing profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/partner-center/manage-account-profiles/get-billing-profile) - looks promising

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2020-05-01/billing-accounts/list?tabs=HTTP
appears to be the endpoint I need, however it never returns any Billing Accounts for any of my tenants.